# Scheduling notification using Timer android

Tags: java, android

I'm using a timer to schedule a notifcation

```
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2011, 2, 6, 16, 50);
    long task = date.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();



    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            triggerNotification();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, task);
```

The timer will work if I manually enter a long value in the *schedule* method but does nothing it seems if I use the *task* variable. Basically I want to schedule a notification at the stated date and time in the Gregorian Calendar object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work by using this instead of the calendar:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = formatter.parse("02/06/2011 16:28");
timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
```

Comment: Comparing the two approaches, I now see what was wrong in the first one : months are zero based in GregorianCalendar, this means that the first code triggered a notification for the 6th of March, rather than the 6th of February.

Answer (score 0):

If the task you're scheduling is a while off the `AlarmManager` class might also be worth looking at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
private void createStatusBarNotification(final String contentTitle, final String contentText, final String tickerText, final long millisec)
{ 
    //Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 2));//in next 2 minutes
    long f = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 2);
    //super.webView.loadUrl("javascript: alert('::"+millisec+","+f+"')");
    Date date = new Date(millisec);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            createNotification( contentTitle,  contentText,  tickerText,  millisec);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, date);            
}
```